# NullPointerException with geocoder on Maps V2 - Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, google-maps-android-api-2

I'am a new android developer and I'm trying to do an app that use the Google Maps to get the current city. I'am using this method to get the city:

```
public String getLocal(double latitude, double longitude)  {

    String cidade = "";
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
         addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 3);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    cidade = addresses.get(0).getLocality();

    return cidade;
}
```

Sometimes he works, and sometimes when a change the GPS mode like: "Device Only" the app crashes. Can someone to help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: While you are getting this exception, did you try printing it using e.printStackTrace()?

Comment: What line is the NPE coming up on? looks like probably on address.get(0)? Are you using Android Studio? You should think about using annotations for all the places where you are dereferencing things that can be null (Java 8 and Swift have optionals to prevent these situations).

Comment: Have you tried using `Logcat` for details?

Comment: My problem was at the LocationManager, I was using without a Try/Catch. Thanks for everyone! :)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [getFromLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)):

**Returns**

a list of Address objects. Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available.

This means you can't just go ahead call addresses.get(0).getLocality().
You have to first make sure `addresses != null`, and that `addresses.size() > 0`

Comment: Hi! I add this test, but the error continue. Only when I change from 'Device Only' to 'High Accuracy Mode'! :(

Comment: Exists some way to get the state and city name from a not so complicated way? I am staying crazy with this problem!! :(

Answer (score 0):

if u want to get the current location on your cellular device then use this code for getting the lognitude and and the altitude of the place using the cellular network

**gpslocator.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;


import android.app.Activity;

import android.location.Address;

import android.location.Geocoder;

import android.location.Location;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;


public class GPSLOCATOR extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,

OnConnectionFailedListener {

LocationClient mLocationClient;
private TextView addressLabel;
private TextView locationLabel;
private Button getlocationbtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpslocator);

    locationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    addressLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    getlocationbtn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this , this );

    getlocationbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //mconnection
        Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        String msg = "Current Location :"+Double.toString(currentLocation.getLatitude())+" , "+ Double.toString(currentLocation.getLongitude());

        locationLabel.setText(msg);

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),Locale.getDefault());

        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try { 
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), 1);

        }catch(IOException e1) {
            Log.e("loctionsampleActivity","IO Exception in getFromLocation()");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e2) {
            String errorstring = "Illegal arguments"+Double.toString(currentLocation.getLatitude())+" , "+ Double.toString(currentLocation.getLongitude())+"passed to the address";
            Log.e("LocationSampleActivity", errorstring);
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(addresses!=null&& addresses.size()>0){
            Address address= addresses.get(0);

            String addressText = String.format("%s, %s,%s",
                    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0)   :       " ",address.getLocality(),address.getCountryName());

            addressLabel.setText(addressText);
        }
        }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mLocationClient.connect();
        locationLabel.setText("connected....");

    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected (Bundle arg0) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "connection connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(this, "conection failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "connection disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**gpslocator.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="get location" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="location " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="address" />



</LinearLayout>
```

use this permission in **Mainfest**

```
 <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

WHEN YOUR DATA CONNECTION WILL BE ON THEN YOU WILL HAVE THE CITY ADDRESS IN THE ADDRESS TEXT FIELD

HOPE THIS WILL HELP U .... :)